# What is causing my iOS app screen to suddenly be so small?

Tags: ios

I removed the reference to the Launch Image file, and since doing so, my iOS app's screen is perhaps half the normal pixels.

What exactly is going on here? The sizing is all wrong now.

I have now set my launch image to this:

[image: iOS]

Comment: You want to implement a `LaunchScreen.storyboard` --- see: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/launch-screen/

Comment: I do not want to implement a storyboard, I want to use a static image

Comment: Then add a `UIImageView` to your LaunchScreen storyboard.

Comment: So do I create a new XIB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top menu bar, select:

```
File -> New -> File...
```

In the `User Interface` section, select:

```
`LaunchScreen`
```

Name it whatever you want -- although, `LaunchScreen` makes it easy to remember what it is.

That will create a "default" `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. Open that file, remove anything that was put there by default (assuming you don't want it there), add a `UIImageView` (with desired constraints / content mode) and set its image to the one you want to use.

Go back to Project / General and select your new file from the `Launch Screen File` drop-down list.

---

**Edit**

- Create your `LaunchScreen.storyboard` file as described above.
- In Xcode, right-click on the new file and select `Open As -> Source Code`
- Delete everything there
- Copy and Paste the below
- Right-click on the file again and select `Open As -> Interface Builder - Storyboard`
- You'll now have view controller with a `UIImageView`
- Select that `UIImageView` and set the image you want to use

Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14868" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14824"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="I7P-As-0qv">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="I7P-As-0qv" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" id="LbD-lu-DG0"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="I7P-As-0qv" secondAttribute="bottom" id="XYw-o5-Ng5"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="I7P-As-0qv" secondAttribute="trailing" id="rR7-d3-qfd"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="I7P-As-0qv" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" id="wyA-cp-XGv"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="53" y="375"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

If you have trouble with any of that, you need to spend a few minutes reading up on how to use Xcode / Interface Builder / Storyboard.

Comment: How do I add a UIImageView? I don’t do a ton of native iOS development

Comment: Either google `Xcode storyboard tutorial` or start here: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev31645f17f

Comment: And there's absolutely no way to shortcut this process at all?

Comment: I don't care if it is done right right now, I have a deadline and have to do something immediately. I can redo it correctly later, if there's any possible faster way.

Comment: @CecilRodriguez - see the edit in my answer. I don't think there can be any more of a shortcut way to do it.